# Win32 custom message box

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface, hook, subclass

I want to make a custom message box. What I want to customize is the button's text.

```
MessageBoxW(
  NULL,
  L"Target folder already exists. Do you want to overwrite the folder?",
  L"No title",
  MB_YESNOCANCEL | MB_ICONQUESTION
  );
```

I'd like to just change the buttons text to `Overwrite`, `Skip`, `Cancel`.
What's the most simple way?

I have to make this as having same look and feel with Windows default messagebox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said by others, a typical way is to create a dialog resource and have a completely independent dialog, which GUI you need to design in the way that it looks like standard dialog (to meet your request for feel and look). If you want to accept text messages, you might probably need to add code which resizes the window appropriately.

Still, there is another option for those who feel like diving into advanced things. While `MessageBox` API does not offer much for fint tuning, you still have `SetWindowsHookEx` in your hands. Having registgered the hook, you can intercept standard `MessageBox` window procedure and subclass it in the way you like.

Typical things include:

- changing button text
- adding more controls
- adding timed automatic close

Hooking standard window can do all of those.

UPD. Hey, I realized I have some code with `SetWindowsHookEx` to share: http://alax.info/blog/127

Comment: Isn't adding controls to a messagebox with window hooks bad? Because what would happen if a next release of Windows adds some other controls to the messagebox, or moves them around?

Comment: @cpp_prog: yes, one should rather think twice before doing this. On the other hand if all you want it self-closing then why not reuse well done message box instead of making your own from the very start.

Comment: `CMessageBoxT::Hook` at the top of AdvancedMessageBoxes01.cpp there?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still confused I did find `T:Hook()` but... `ExtractCreateWndData()` not even sure why that's needed... I'll keep reading and shuttee for now...  OK yes, you want `T*` but... yikes so much in here I don't understand.  I really need to quit the C# and get back to basics.

Comment: `ExtractCreateWndData` is as far as I remember ATL's call. If you can build the project, just step it through and you should see where it's getting you.

Comment: It's clear you are using `ExtractCreateWndData` to retrieve the class pointer, but I guess in my imagination I thought that would be handled through an `lParam` or something...  I'm sure yours is safer / better, but now I have to read more APIs.  I just want to change the text on a `MessageBox()` button so I can annoy a family member with most minimal lines of code.  (kind of insertable into program as it were)  A 500k DLL with internal resource files wouldn't be very elegant.

Comment: I upgraded to VS2019 for you: https://github.com/roman380/AdvancedMessageBoxes01 you can step it through (you might still need to download WTL though)

Comment: My plan is: `OnInitDialg() {EnumChildWindows();  TB_GETBUTTONTEXT(); PostMessage(WM_SETTEXT, ???); }`  Does that pseudocode sound remotely close?  I don't have a compiler on this computer.  And won't have time till later for the coding part... (am I supposed to delete these comments for cleanliness?)

Comment: Sounds about right. You can also pick the window by its ID instead of doing enum. You will need to look up the ID constant using Spy++.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an own dialog. Or you could use a window hook as described [in this article](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-messagebox).

An archived version of the article can be found on [web.archive.com](http://web.archive.org/web/20170924110413/http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-messagebox).

Comment: This link is now dead and there isn't enough information here to look up the article in a web search.

Comment: You could use web.archive.org to  view an earlier version of the linked article.

Comment: And you could edit the link...  Personally, I just chose a different answer, yours wasn't the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Make a dialog resource (with a GUI editor, or by hand) and call [`DialogBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it. There's no way to alter `MessageBox` behaviour, other than what's supported by its arguments.

That said, your message box can very well use stock Yes/No options.

Answer (score 1):

The [task dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787471%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functionality introduced in Vista does exactly what you want and follows the prevailing system theme. However, if you have to support XP, then this will be of little comfort to you.

Comment: Of course, today this is very much the way to do it. (XP is no longer supported.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I just stumbled upon it now.
I would like to expand the other answers in regards to using a `TaskDialog` instead of a `MessageBox`. Here's a concise example of using a TaskDialog to do precisely what was asked; *change the button's texts*:

```c
const TASKDIALOG_BUTTON buttons[] = { {IDYES, L"Overwrite"}, {IDNO, L"Skip"}, {IDCANCEL, L"Cancel"} };
TASKDIALOGCONFIG taskDialogConfig = {
    .cbSize = sizeof(TASKDIALOGCONFIG),
    .pszMainIcon = TD_WARNING_ICON, // TaskDialog does not support a question icon; see below
    .pButtons = buttons,
    .cButtons = ARRAYSIZE(buttons),
    .pszWindowTitle = L"No title",
    .pszContent = L"Target folder already exists. Do you want to overwrite the folder?"
};
TaskDialogIndirect(&taskDialogConfig, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Some noteworthy things:

- You need to use `TaskDialogIndirect`, not the basic `TaskDialog` function
- when not specifying a parent window, the icon specified in `pszMainIcon` is displayed in the title bar as well
- There is no equivalent to the MessageBox's `MB_ICONQUESTION`, quoting a quote from [this forumpost](http://forum.codejock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=17275&title=taskdialog-builtin-question-icon-is-missing): `Don't use the question mark icon to ask questions. Again, use the question mark icon only for Help entry points. There is no need to ask questions using the question mark icon anyway—it's sufficient to present a main instruction as a question.`
- checking which button was selected would have to be done by passing a pointer to an int as the second argument of `TaskDialogIndirect` and checking its value on return (the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-taskdialogindirect) should be pretty clear)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1239/XMessageBox-A-reverse-engineered-MessageBox) is a small open source library that allows you to customize Message Boxes. Developed by [Hans Ditrich](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=15759).
I have successfully used it in another [POC](https://github.com/haephrati/Haephrati_EmbedData_Library) that allows [embedding a custom icon in such MessageBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1275122/How-to-Embed-Resources-in-a-Static-Library) that can be called even from a [Console application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-1-create?view=vs-2019).

I should also point to the [Task Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/task-dialogs). Here is an example of using it:

```
int nButtonPressed = 0;
TaskDialog(NULL, hInst, 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDS_APPLICATION_TITLE),
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDS_DOSOMETHING), 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDS_SOMECONTENT), 
    TDCBF_OK_BUTTON | TDCBF_CANCEL_BUTTON,
    TD_WARNING_ICON, 
    &nButtonPressed);

if (IDOK == nButtonPressed)
{
    // OK button pressed
}
else if (IDCANCEL == nButtonPressed)
{
    // Cancel pressed
}
```

Comment: But why would you do this when you can use task dialogs?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, the question is about customizing MessageBox(). The open source library I pointed to does exactly that. You can customize the MessageBox's buttons, timeout to close, icon, colors and background.

Comment: I see. I might not agree that doing that can be considered best practices (and I really hope the techniques involves only documented parts of the Win32 API and OS), especially not when the task dialog now is present on all modern and supported Windows versions, but I do see that it is a valid answer to the given question.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand thanks! I read the articles of the author https://www.codeproject.com/Members/Hans-Dietrich and he indeed uses some undocumented parts of Win32 api which I find interesting. The “normal” MessageBox is quite limited in my opinion...

Comment: Well, that's why Microsoft developed the task dialog, which is used everywhere in Windows today (e.g., Notepad, Paint, WordPad). The MessageBox function probably dates back to ... Windows 1.0 in the 1980s? I don't know, but certainly it was present in Windows 3.1.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand I expanded my answer accordingly so it will also point out the Task Dialog option which is indeed much more modern and up to date than the old MessageBox