# How do I send windows messages to a MessageBox

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm looking for a way to manipulate a MessageBox like a window, would I have to actually use `CreateWindowEx` and make a tiny window in order to get the full functionality of a window including using things such as `WM_GETTEXT` and `WM_SETTEXT` or is there some way I can send these messages to a MessageBox? If I absolutely can't send windows messages to a MessageBox, then is there alternate methods less complicated then using `CreateWindowEx` to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: What hwnd would I send it to? How do I get the handle of the MessageBox? I thought messagebox was an int, would I just cast it to hwnd then?

Comment: http://alax.info/blog/127 - hooking `MessageBox` to alter/amend it; see also [Win32 custom message box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847620/win32-custom-message-box)

Comment: The same way you get a handle to any other window. `FindWindow`, `FindWindowEx`, a CBT hook...

Comment: @chris I don't quite understand, that function you linked only returns one HWND, what if multiple HWND's match the parameters? For example, I have a button that calls the MessageBox function and the button is pressed multiple times and then FindWindow or FindWindowEx function is called, how then do I get the function to return the right MessageBox?

Comment: @user1958850, With the former two, there's no way to tell which it picks. With hooking your own application, you'd get the proper handle each time one is created.

Comment: Why don't you just use your own Dialog box template in an RC file.  Then use DialogBox() API to launch modally - just like MessageBox. Then you can send (and handle) whatever message you want with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a thread-local `WH_CBT` hook when you call `MessageBox()` to get its window handle.  You can then send messages to it like any other window.

```
// if you need to customize MessageBox() across threads,
// store this variable in a TLS (thread-local storage) slot...
HHOOK hHook; 

LRESULT CALLBACK MyCBTHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (nCode)
    {
        case HCBT_CREATEWND: // window is being created
        case HCBT_ACTIVATE:  // window is being activated
        {
            HWND hWnd = (HWND) wParam;
            // use hWnd as needed...
            break;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook);
}

int MyMessageBox(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType)
{
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC)&MyCBTHook, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
    int iResult = MyMessageBox(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    return iResult;
}
```