# msgbox button type in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How to set a message box which has buttons like "ok" and "cancel"? Also can we name our own names for the buttons? And can we write source codes for those buttons, like

```
ok.click, form1.show() and if cancel.click form5.show()
msgbox()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MessageBoxButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx) enum to specify different kinds of buttons on messagebox and use [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx) after the button is clicked to specify different actions for each type of messagebox button.
Or [create your own MessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847620/win32-custom-message-box)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show("put your text here", "here the title of you message", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Hand)
```

after the second comma [,] you can put the type of buttons and at the last you can put the icon you think it will best suit your message box

regards

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
If (MsgBox("Your Text", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "MessageBox Title") = MsgBoxResult.Ok) Then
        Form1.Show()
    Else
        form5.show()
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple message box:

```
If MessageBox.Show("some msg", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = DialogResult.Cancel Then
    ' you cancel it, so i will show another message box
EndIf
```