# How to increase size of font in MessageBox c++ builder

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, c++builder-6

*I'm using c++ builder (bcb6)

I would like enlarge font size of message box without creating custom message box.

I searched over google and find that it's possible to use by WM_SETFONT.

I tried doing:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0,"WC_DIALOG","Questions!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,400, 100, 100, 100,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
HFONT hFont=CreateFont (30, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS, "Arial");
SendMessage (hWnd, WM_SETFONT, WPARAM (hFont), TRUE);
MessageBox(hWnd,message.c_str(),"Info",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

And it dorsn't work..

Any suggestions please?

Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: You can't change the font in a MessageBox ([read this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e5240b4-dee1-433d-b868-016338d2b0d7/change-font-size-for-messageboxshow-dialogs?forum=winforms)).

Comment: Not related to your question, but don't use `HFONT` like that, it causes resource leak. Is "Borland C++" and "C++ Builder" the same thing?

Comment: @MichaelWalz As I understand, your link related C#. I need it for C++ builder borland (bcb6).

Comment: @Programmer At first sight, it looks if it is C# related, but if you read the article, you'll see that the C# MessageBox boils down to a call to the MessageBox in user32.dll, and that is exactly the MessageBox _you_ are using. It's not a borland related problem either but a win32 related problem.

Comment: If you need a message box that is not the standard message box, you'll have to implement your own message box. What you are trying to implement is not a supported scenario. It will fail in many ways (e.g. by not properly sizing or laying out the text).

Comment: You really need to read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx). The *hWnd* parameter to `MessageBox` designates it's **owner**. At any rate, what you are trying will not end well. If you need a custom dialog, implement a custom dialog.

Comment: @IInspectable I want a solution without creating custom message box. I see there is solution with window hook. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847620/win32-custom-message-box but it still doesn't work to me

Comment: If you want a solution without creating a custom message box, then you cannot change the font. Is it really that difficult to digest?

Comment: I just want to change font size wihout creating custom message box-isn't is possible?

Comment: @Programmer you're talking about the window hook solution but in the code you have posted there is no attempt to do any window hooking

Comment: BTW it would be less effort to create a custom dialog than to implement the window hook, probably...

Comment: @M.M Any ideas how to create custom dialog with only enlarged text size ?

Comment: Yes, in fact you told me how to do it already. thanks for improving my knowledge

Comment: @M.M I don't understand your comment..  I still don't know how to implement it using window hook

Comment: Read the pages that show examples of implementing it via window hook, and follow the examples.  If you need to be spoon-fed you're in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing specific in C++Builder for changing font in a MessageBox. Your options are:

- Make a custom dialog
- Use window hooks to change the default MessageBox, via the Windows API.

Both of these are described in more detail with linked examples on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847620/win32-custom-message-box).  If you have tried something from that thread and it didn't work then post the code that you tried as a new question.